# An app to use the mac trackpad like a touchscreen

Tags: mac, trackpad

Is there an app that can set the cursor position directly from your finger placement on the trackpad?

I found the trackpad commander (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205770) as part of voiceover, but as far as I know there is no way to use it to directly control the mouse pointer rather than the voiceover cursor.

Comment: Enter "macbook trackpad as tablet" in your favourite search engine. "Inklet" is one of the more popular ones.

Comment: Bear in mind that the trackpad is a different ratio from most displays (16 : 11.5); and if your screen is large, it's going to be hypersensitive to the slightest movement. By default, the trackpad input accelerates the pointer with faster movement, so you can span larger distances, and also have precise control by moving more slowly.